# Compare lists integers values

Tags: python, list, compare

I have been trying to compare a list values with the column number of an array in order to save the values which have the same column value in an array.

```
prob_val = [[.01 .04 0.3 0.1 .5],
            [.05 .02 0.1 0.7 .1],
            [.04 .05 0.4 0.1 .6],
            [.31 .03 0.2 0.1 .5],
            [.18 .01 0.1 0.6 .1],....
            [.12 .02 0.2 0.4 .2]]

predic_val = [[0],[0],[1],[0],[1],[2],[3],.....,[1],[2]]


values = [prob_val[predic_val==i][:,i] for i in range(5)]
```

I mean for all position for predic_val == 0 is going to take the values for the column 0 in prob_val.

but when i ran the code i get some error as:
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 194 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Trying with other code:

```
test = [[0,2,3,4,5],
        [6,7,8,9,10],
        [11,12,13,14,15],
        [16,17,18,19,20],
        [21,22,23,24,25]]

pree = [[0],
        [7],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]]

vector = []
for i in range(5):
  for l in range(len(pree)):
    if pree[l] == i:
      new = test[l][i]
      vector.append(new)
      print("l es:",l)

print("vector: ",vector)
print("pree[l]: ",pree[0])
```

But in this case the line **if pree[l] == i:** looks like is not comparing the values so vector is always empty.

Do you have any idea to do this either first way or second way?

Comment: Your check is incorrect. `pree[l]` is a list item. Try, `pree[l][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = [[0,2,3,4,5],
        [6,7,8,9,10],
        [11,12,13,14,15],
        [16,17,18,19,20],
        [21,22,23,24,25]]

pree = [[0],
        [7],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]]

vector = []
for i in range(5):
    for l in range(len(pree)):
        if pree[l][0] == i:    # Correction was needed here 
            new = test[l][i]
            vector.append(new)
            print("l es:", l)

print("vector: ",vector)
print("pree[l]: ",pree[0])
```